# Fetching data successfully from firebase database but unable to display it in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

MessageAdapter Class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{
private List<Messages> mMessagesList;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

public MessageAdapter (List<Messages>mMessagesList)

{
    this.mMessagesList = mMessagesList;
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_custom,parent,false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return new MessageViewHolder(V);
}



public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView messageText;
    public MessageViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        messageText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
    }
}




@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String current_user_id = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Messages messages = mMessagesList.get(position);
        String from_user = messages.getFrom();

//        if (from_user!=null && from_user.equals(current_user_id)){
//                holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background1);
//                holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.red(R.color.red));
//            }else {
//                holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background2);
//                holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.red(R.color.black));
//            }

        holder.messageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    }

@Override
public  int getItemCount() {
    return mMessagesList.size();
}
}
```

Chat.java

```
    private RecyclerView messageList;
private List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private MessageAdapter mAdapter;

String MessageSenderId;
String MessageRecieverId;

final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");

    messageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);
//        messageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    messageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 private void fetchMessages() {

   rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            Log.d("Tag", dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

XML LAYOUTS

ActivityChat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
>
<TextView
 android:textColor="@color/white"
 android:id="@+id/name"
 android:layout_width="275dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/message_list"
 android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
 android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<Button
 android:id="@+id/add_image"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:id="@+id/input_message"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_message" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Send"
android:id="@+id/send_message"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="12dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/messages_text_background"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Before instead of a `recyclerview` I used a listview and it worked fine just like expected... Then for obvious reasons, I switched to recycle view and I am having this problem

Screenshot = https://ibb.co/gcve67

In the logcat I tried to fetch the data using Log.d and it worked... so I know that the data is getting fetched but just not able to display it in `recyclerview`... Recyclerview rules had also slightly changed since the last time I used to I'm not sure whether the way I used is correct... if that's correct I strongly believe there's something wrong with the layouts but just can't figure it out... Please help... Stuck here for weeks

Comment: had you make `adapter`?

Comment: Check this out. In that blog he is using local data. You can modify the type of data based on your requirement. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Check after you called notifyDataSetChanged on adapter, what is the item count being returned

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I checked my adapter with the links u guys provided and other tutorials as well... still not able to figure out what the problem is... please help... anybody mind checking my complete code using teamviewer or something please?

Comment: Can you share your database structure and Log.d() output? I think problem lies 'Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);' It is not able to convert datasnapshot to object properly. Can you try "Message message = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue(Message.class)"